# ChatGPT 3.5 api array length and prompt calculation

Tags: openai-api

ChatGPT documentation
Messages must be an array of message objects, where each object has a role (either "system", "user", or "assistant") and content (the content of the message). Conversations can be as short as 1 message or fill many pages

I want to know how many arrays I can send to chatGPT 3.5 and with how much data will it be charged against token or just the last array item will be charged and rest will be charged less.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424110/4961700

Comment: Why not ask ChatGPT?

Comment: You will be charged for the size of each request prompt + response. They don't care that your request contains the previous conversation. If you want to estimate the size in the tokens, you'll have to use a tokenizer on your side similar to that GPT is using (https://gptforwork.com/guides/openai-gpt3-tokens)